# Read multiple images in R

Tags: r

I have 500 images in a folder and have to process them with ReadImage(), rgb_2gray(), resizeImage() and then store them in a vector. I've tried different approaches but i don't know how to access each image and then store them in the vector. Each image has data I need to analize.

Thanks for you help!

This is what i just tried:

```
library(OpenImageR)
setwd("C:/Users/Idoia/Desktop/UOC/UOC 2020/Machine learning/PEC 1")
lista<-list.files("C:/Users/Idoia/Desktop/UOC/UOC 2020/Machine learning/PEC 1/normal", 
                  all.files = FALSE, full.names = TRUE)
df<-data.frame()
for (i in length(lista)) {
  pic<-readImage(lista[i])
  pic<-rgb_2gray(pic)
  pic<-resizeImage(pic, width = 64, height = 64)
  pic<-as.vector(pic)
  pre_pic<-t(pic)
  df<-rbind(df,pre_pic)
}
```

It only stores one row and I need 500 rows. It seems like it is only reading the first image.

Comment: I suspect you'll have to store them as a list. `mypics <- list(); mypics[[i]] <- ReadImage(pic[i])` Something like that.

Comment: Can you comment an approach that you tried?

Comment: I just edited my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop.

```
library(OpenImageR)
setwd("~/Images/")
Files <- list.files()
Results <- list()
for(i in seq_along(Files)){
      Image <- readImage(Files[i])
      Resized <- resizeImage(Image, width = 200, height = 200)
      Gray <- rgb_2gray(Resized)
      Results[[i]] <- Gray
}
```

Then you can access the results using `[[` on the `Results` list.

```
imageShow(Results[[1]])
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the problem by adding 1:length

```
df<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(lista)) {
pic<-readImage(lista[i])
pic<-rgb_2gray(pic)
pic<-resizeImage(pic, width = 64, height = 64)
pic<-as.vector(pic)
pre_pic<-t(pic)
df<-rbind(df,pre_pic)}
```

Thanks everyone!! :)